# How to sort an Excel sheet by two different columns

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

Let's assume a chart with only values in the first two columns A and B like this

[image]

First I'd like to sort the chart alphabetically by column A, i.e. the Xs at top, then the Ys and the Zs.

The 2nd move should be a sorting of column B considering column A, i.e. keeping the block of Xs and sort their numbers in column B. The same with the blocks of Y and Z.

The 1st step works fine with the following code:

```
Sub sort()
Dim SortClmn As String
Dim Area As String
Area= "A1:B10"
SortClmn = "A"
ActiveSheet.Range(Area).Sort _
Key1:=Range(SortClmn & "1"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
Header:=xlGuess, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

How do I need to change this code to apply the 2nd step?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to sort Column B and then sort Column A, this will achieve your desired effect.
Use the same method you used, but sort first column b then column a.

If I modify your code it would look as follows

```
Sub sort()
Dim SortClmn As String
Dim Area As String
Area = "A1:B10"
SortClmn = "B"
ActiveSheet.Range(Area).sort _
Key1:=Range(SortClmn & "1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
Header:=xlGuess, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
Area = "A1:B10"
SortClmn = "A"
ActiveSheet.Range(Area).sort _
Key1:=Range(SortClmn & "1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
Header:=xlGuess, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Ricards but this code only sorts the 2nd column. The first step is somehow overruled.

Comment: I did a test, sorted both columns, so the column A was sorted after column B, but B remained sub sorted to A. definitely worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

1. Record a macro;
2. Select the table;
3. In the ribbon - Data > Sort;

[image]

4. Select the first column that you want to sort;
5. Press <kbd>Add Level</kbd>;
6. Select the second column that you want to sort;
7. See the generated code;;
8. Refactor it, avoinding `Select`, `Activate` and putting the string variables;

[Range.Sort Method MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-sort-method-excel)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub sort()
    lastRow = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.sort
     .SortFields.Clear
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1:A" & lastRow), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1:B" & lastRow), Order:=xlAscending
     .SetRange Range("A2:B" & lastRow)
     .Header = xlNo
     .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Something like this?